# Why "how i met your mother" not as famous as "F.R.I.E.N.D.S"?

Tags: friends, how-i-met-your-mother

I had watched both "how I met your mother" and "F.R.I.E.N.D.S". However I compared the two, I think HIMYM is much more appealing,realistic,humorous,sentimental, proper story,screenplay than the F.R.I.E.N.D.S . But why is HIMYM not that popular yet?

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: I've heard of [Friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friends), but what show is "F.R.I.E.N.D.S."?

Comment: Why isn’t _Alf_ more popular than _Seinfeld_? Why isn’t _Alf_ more popular than _Everyone Loves Raymond_? Why wasn’t _Alf_ named _Everyone  Loves Alf_?

Comment: …because fewer people watched it? @Freeman - the show's logo was actually stylised as F⠐R⠐I⠐E⠐N⠐D⠐S, though that's not its official name.